# ¿Cómo se dice “pattern” en español, cuando refiere a una búsqueda de semejanzas de palabras?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, informática

¿Cómo se dice “pattern” en español, cuando se refiere a una búsqueda de semejanzas de palabras en la programación de computadoras?

Hice [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/776) en [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) en que no sabia qué palabra usar. Las siguientes palabras parecen ser traducciones de unos sentidos de "pattern", pero no tengo mucha confianza que sean lo que significa para la programación:

- `modelo`
- `patrón`
- `diseño`

Cuando pienso de `patrón` pienso en un patrocinador (una acepción de "patron" en inglés).

Comment: ¿Por qué se te ocurre necesariamente el adjetivo bondadoso, para el concepto de patrón?

Comment: Estaba pensando de un patrocinador, pero no sabia la palabra en español hasta ahora. Hice el cambio en la pregunta. ¡Gracias por preguntarme sobre esto! Aprendí una palabra nueva.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yo en clases siempre he escuchado a los profesores hablar de "patrón", aunque siempre con la sospecha de que era más una traducción libre desde el inglés.

Sin embargo, en la [definición de patrón en el diccionario de la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?w=patr%C3%B3n), en la octava acepción, dice:

> 8. m. Modelo que sirve de muestra para sacar otra cosa igual.

Esta sería la acepción más cercana a lo que buscas.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Su experiencia en clase (además de la acepción muy clara) hace su respuesta mu convincente.

Comment: Como bien dice Nicolás 'patrón' es la palabra. Referido a búsqueda de semejanzas suele aplicarse el término 'reconocimiento de patrones'.

Comment: Un **patrón** es un modelo para reconocer estructuras más complejas. En visión artificial o en reconocimiento de textos se usa *pattern recognition* y siempre lo he utilizado como reconocimiento de patrones.